# Flag Post Warning

Tags: support, flagging

I was reviewing a post now and due to certain flaws of the post, I had to flag it. Just then  I saw this message at the bottom of the flagging window.
[image]

I checked my flagging history by clicking on the "**review**" link given in the message and this is what I saw...
[image]

So my question is: *Is 1 declined post too many? That too many days back? What am I to understand from this untimed message?*

Any kind of help is welcome.

Comment: I've gotten that message recently as well, my last declined one was about 2 wks prior to the message. I think the system is messed up.

Comment: Don't get bothered at it; I also got this message for 1 `declined` even 2 weeks after that review. So, it is just that you should remember that you had a wrong decision & don't just commit that on the next review; that's it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238170/271002

Comment: @Loong - Please turn that into an answer :)

Comment: Take it easy. It's drawing your attention to the declined flags (which you might otherwise have missed) and prompting you to have a look to see if they imply you need to tune your flagging habits, and not stopping you from flagging.

Comment: BTW [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/213360) (10k+mods now) was definitely Not An Answer.

Answer (score 6):

According to this [meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/271002), flaggers with at least 10 handled flags in the past 7 days where at least 10 % of flags were declined will see the warning when they flag again.

[image: Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!]

Apparently, you just met these criteria when 10 of your flags were handled in the past 7 days and 1 flag (i.e. 10 %) was declined.

Answer (score 5):

The criteria for that message are set to try to catch well meaning but overzealous flaggers early. Your flagging history is very helpful overall and you should look at the declined flag as a chance to tune your understanding of when to flag rather than a big problem.